# Calling std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting, std

`sort` in the C++ standard library is called as:

```
sort (first element, last element);
```

So if I have an array:

```
int a[n];
```

I should call `sort` as:

```
sort(&a[0], &a[n-1]);
```

since `a[0]` is the first element and `a[n-1]` the last. When I do so, however, it doesn't sort the last element. To get a fully sorted array, I must use:

```
sort(&a[0], &a[n]);
```

Why is this?

Comment: `std::sort` works on the iterators [start inclusive, end exclusive). Are you asked why it is designed so ?

Comment: End iterators don't point to any valid element. `&a[n-1]` does, and so isn't used as an end iterator. A pointer to one past the last element of a C-style array is specifically allowed as a valid pointer value (of course you aren't allowed to dereference it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because ranges in stl are always defined as half-open ranges from the fist element iterator to to the "one-past-the-end"-iterator. With C++11 you can use:

```
int a[n];
sort(std::begin(a),std::end(a));
```

Comment: should mention that `std::begin/std::end()` are defined starting with C++11. Otherwise you can just write your own via passing the array by reference to a template or just use `a[n]` as the `end` iterator, as @Neil Kirk pointed out

Answer (score 2):

> Format for sort in STL in c++ is,
>
> ```
> sort (first element, last element);
> ```

No, it's not. You are supposed to provide an iterator for the first element, and a *one-past-the-end* iterator, as you've discovered.

The Standard Library in general uses [semi-open intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals) to describe ranges through iterators. Otherwise it would be impossible for empty ranges to be expressed:

```
// An empty container!
std::vector<int> v;

// Pretend that `v.end()` returns an iterator for the actual last element,
// with the same caveat as `v.begin()` that the case where no elements
// exist gives you some kind of "sentinel" iterator that does not represent
// any element at all and cannot be dereferenced
std::vector<int>::iterator a = v.begin(), b = v.end();

// Oh no, this would think that there's one element!
std::sort(a, b);
```